# Custom exception handling

Tags: c#, exception, windows-phone-8

I am making an app in wp8.1 I want to make sure that during certain process user is not allowed to press the hardware backbutton of windows phone. IF he does then my custom catch block exception should run.

I don't know how to handle the backbutton exception for my app. Please provide any snippet or help you can in making custom exception.

Thanks

```
public class InvalidDataException : ApplicationException 
{
    public InvalidDataException()
    {
    }
    public InvalidDataException(string msg)
        : base(msg)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Implementing control-flow with exceptions is a very bad idea

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Yeah I agree. But he can handle the BackPressed event. I would be surprised if that event is cancellable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set BackPressedEventArgs (e) parameter's Handled property to True , you will block the OS action on this event you can trigger your custom exception.

When you set this property to true OS will stop to navigate back.However , you shouldn't prevent user from terminating your app.Otherwise your app has a change to not get into the Store.

Comment: i am only preventing user  when a particular task is being performed in my app. apart from it user is free to use the button. can we do it by using task.continuewith() . any idea ?

Comment: Not sure , but you can control that task' completion with a simple boolean property.Set Handled to opposite of that property and it'll work as you wanted.And don't forget to set this boolean to true after your task is complete.

Answer (score 0):

At least you can handle the `BackPressed` event.

Have a look at [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.phone.ui.input.hardwarebuttons.backpressed.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp%23code-snippet-1)

I don't think you can cancel this event easily, but you can always `throw` an exception, though it is not good practice.

Happy coding!

**EDIT**

Oh, totally forgot BackPressedEventArgs, though I've used it...
Thats the way to go

Good catch, Burak Kaan Köse